# Typescript carry the parameter type from constructor to class

Tags: typescript

I have a union type declaration for my DTO

```
export enum PropertyType {
  Text = 'text',
  Date = 'date',
  Number = 'number',
  //...
}

export interface PropertyDtoBase {
  prompt?: string;
  required?: boolean;
  // ...
};

export type PropertyDto = PropertyDtoBase & (
  { type: PropertyType.Text; value?: string; } |
  { type: PropertyType.Date; value?: Date; } |
  { type: PropertyType.Number; value?: number; } |
  // ...
);
```

Now I want to generate a class out of this DTO and I want to carry on the type definition for the `value` property. However I only get `unknown` as type.

```
export class Property {
  prompt?: string;
  required?: boolean;
  type?: PropertyType;
  value?: Exclude<ConstructorParameters<typeof Property>[0], undefined>["value"];
  // ...

  public constructor(dto?: PropertyDto) {
    Object.assign(this, dto);
    //...
  }
};

const x = new Property({ type: PropertyType.Text, value: "test" });
if(x.type === PropertyType.Text) {
  x.value // value is unknown here, but should be string
}
```

How can I carry on the type of value from the DTO to the class?

Comment: `x.value` has type `string | number | Date | undefined` not `unknown`. Check this [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WyzGgw)

Comment: You can use generic in the class `Property ` to exploit the TS inference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a class out of your DTO, define that class as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

```
class Property<T extends PropertyDto> {
  prompt?: string;
  required?: boolean;
  type?: T['type'];
  value?: T['value'];

  public constructor(dto?: T) {
    Object.assign(this, dto);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
const x = new Property({ type: PropertyType.Text, value: 'test' });

// TypeScript knows x.type equals PropertyType.Text
console.log(x.value) // "test"
```

Notice that you don't even need to check if `x.type` equals `PropertyType.Text` in order to know that `x.value` is a `string` type. TypeScript becomes aware of it!